# How to show data as per my requirement in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, pivot

here is my table structure

```
create table DailyFinishJobsHistory
(
   RowID   INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),  
  [Job Type]  Varchar(16) NOT NULL,  
  [No of Jobs]  INT NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),  
  [Turnaround Time] DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),  
  [One Day Per]  DECIMAL(8,2),
  CreatedDate datetime DEFAULT (GetDate())
)
```

### this way data is stored in table screen shot

[image]

now i have to show the data this way & order by date asc and where clause will be there where i need to specify two date.

```
date   OUR_No of jobs  OUR_Turnaround_time OUR_One day per Salesnew_ of jobs Salesnew_no of jobs Salesnew_turnaround_time this way i need to show...
```

i guess i need to use pivot but whatever i tried did not work. so any help will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: What are these columns should come from: `OUT_No`, `OUR_Turnaround_time`, `OUR_One`? Can you explain with plain English? Or paste the desired results of the sample data in your question.

Comment: _whatever i tried did not work_, can you post what you tried?

Comment: just see the job type column in my screen shot and there u find OUR,SalesNew etc just i need to show OUR_no of job and show the no of jobs for OUR and i have to show other same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question and requirements are not very clear but I am going to take a guess that you want the following:

```
select
  convert(varchar(10), createddate, 120) date,
  sum(case when [job type] = 'OUR' then [No of Jobs] else 0 end) OurNoOfJobs,
  sum(case when [job type] = 'OUR' then [Turnaround Time] else 0 end) OurTurnaroundTime,
  sum(case when [job type] = 'OUR' then [One Day Per] else 0 end) OurOneDayPer,
  sum(case when [job type] = 'SALESNEW' then [No of Jobs] else 0 end) SalesNewNoOfJobs,
  sum(case when [job type] = 'SALESNEW' then [Turnaround Time] else 0 end) SalesNewTurnaroundTime,
  sum(case when [job type] = 'SALESNEW' then [One Day Per] else 0 end) SalesNewOneDayPer
from DailyFinishJobsHistory
group by convert(varchar(10), createddate, 120);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5677d/1).

This uses an aggregate function and a CASE expression to convert and your rows of data into columns using the `sum` function to aggregate the values the in columns that you want.

Comment: there will be a problem if two new job type added like OUR or SALESNew. if two new column is added then problem occur.if i follow your query then i need to change when any new jobtype of any new columns added. i want to have query in such a way as a result i do not have to touch if any new jobtype of any new columns added.if possible guide me. thanks